# Editing duplicate values in a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a DataGrid View pulling some items from my database. What I want to achieve is to be able to edit the pack size or the bar_code fields. I am aware on how to update values in a database but how would I go about doing it if the data is the same? Meaning in many instances a bar code would have multiple pack sizes that is related to the one bar code number. Let's say I have the below screenshot. A data entry error was made and the bar_code and PackSize columns are the exact same. I want to change the first bar code to "1234." How would I achieve this? I can't say update barcode to 'textBox1.Text' where bar_code = '771313166386' because it would then change both data. How do I go about only focusing on one row of data at a time?

[image]

Comment: This question is by far too broad. What have you tried to achieve this? Show your code. Btw.: why is this question tagged with C#?

Comment: It's winforms, c# code in it. Would think showing the code would be pointless seeing that I explained the update function I did would only update all the rows

Comment: But the question in itself isn´t related to neither winforms nor C#, it´s just about modifying data within a database with SQL, isn´t it?

Comment: The script would be within my c# code @HimBromBeere

Comment: There has to be some field (or fields) that uniquely identifies each record that you want to update. Otherwise, each update is non-deterministic.

Comment: @PeterAbolins unfortunately there isn't. I looked through their table thoroughly and their isn't

Comment: What is your primary key column? It must have one primary key column

Comment: So... if I am understanding this correctly, there exist a lot of rows in the table which are fully identical to each other?

Comment: @PeterAbolins yes exactly. From what I am seeing it was a poorly constructed table

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this query to update only the first row:

```
UPDATE TOP (1) my_table
SET bar_code = '1234'
WHERE bar_code = '771313166386'
```

> You should have an `auto-increment` `id` column or a `Primary key` in your table.

Comment: This is good. Is this also possible if I want to update let's say the second row? `Update Top (2)`or something along those lines

Comment: Rows are **equals** before the update, update the second row doesn't make sense, that's the same to update the first since they're equals and there is not a `first` or a `second` row without a **Primary key**. Be carefull, `Update Top (2)` will update the first two found rows.

Comment: Oh I understand. Thank you, reasoned it out incorrectly.

Comment: Updating the second row will be trivial, if you changed the bar_code for the first one, since the row that used to be second is now first.

Comment: Sure @PeterAbolins, but i think the OP intended to understand the query **before the update**, otherwise it would be a normal update query

Comment: My point was that the purpose of the update would be to reduce the number of identical rows for the original bar_code. So, a subsequent update for that bar_code would have a different first row?

Comment: Further... I think that trying to provide a clean logical solution is not going to be possible. The DB design is flawed, there are duplicate records, and that is just how it is. Your solution allows the OP to update the first record, and I would suggest he repeats the exact update query (with a slight difference in what the bar_code or pack_size is set to) for the subsequent rows in the duplicated set.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you handle the logic of data duplicate manipulation at the backend rather than pulling them inside the grid and handle it there.

The following query will help you retrieve the duplicate records based on the mentioned columns. You can change it to UPDATE or DELETE as per your requirement.

```
-- Using cte and ranking function
    ;With CTE
    As
    (
        Select 
            Product,
            Description,
            BarCode,
            PackSize
            Row_Number() Over(Partition By Product, BarCode, PackSize Order By Product) As RowNum
        From YourTable
    )
    Select * From CTE
    -- Where RowNum > 1;
```

Hope this is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

This might not help you directly in your answer. But, it is important to mention that your table design is incorrect. You should ensure the [data integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity) by creating a primary key in your table.

So when you need to update a product you have only one row to update.

Then you can add more tables and use foreign key references between them.

Comment: I understand but it is not my table per say. It is a table in the company I work. Have no choice but to work with it

Answer (score 1):

You need to uniquely represent the products. As per your sample data, I guess that there isn't any primary key on your table.
What you can do is either specify a unique constraint on columns to ensure that this type of data entry cannot be done.
If you cannot come up with list of columns to uniquely identify the rows, you can use surrogate keys by specifying `Identity` column and then while updating, always put a constraint where `thisIdentityColumn=value`

Answer (score 0):

> A data entry error was made and the bar_code and PackSize columns are
>   the exact same

I think this is the key. Essentially, the exact duplicates are unintentional, and the rows should be unique. Further it looks like `bar_code` + `pack_size` is your primary key (subject to data being entered correctly).

So, when you do an update, simply update the first row found that matches a bar_code and a pack_size. If it isn't unique, then the update should ensure that you are one step closer to unique rows in the database.

If you need a non-verbal answer, let me know.